# Using variable in QgsDefaultValue() of PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, postgresql

This is not working for me:

```
    # set default values
    fields = {
        'target_geometry_set_id': self.poly_set_id,
        'target_geometry_type': 'Polygon',
        'target_geometry_source': 'qgis',
        'target_geometry_last_modified_by': os.getlogin()}
    for field in fields.keys():
        field_idx = self.poly_layer.fields().indexOf(field)
        self.poly_layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(field_idx, QgsDefaultValue('@fields[field]'))
        print(self.poly_layer.defaultValue(field_idx))
```

The print statement ends up printing out None and when digitizing a new feature I get an error because this PostgreSQL layer needs non null values for those fields.

How do I properly use the @ expression to use a variable for the default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format worked:

```
    # set default values
    fields = {
        'target_geometry_set_id': self.poly_set_id,
        'target_geometry_type': 'Polygon',
        'target_geometry_source': 'qgis',
        'target_geometry_last_modified_by': os.getlogin()}
    for field in fields.keys():
        field_idx = self.poly_layer.fields().indexOf(field)
        self.poly_layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(field_idx, QgsDefaultValue(f'\'{fields[field]}\''))
        print(self.poly_layer.defaultValue(field_idx))
```

I would love to know what the documentation meant by using the @ symbol though.

Comment: The documentation is not referring to a Python variable which you have defined yourself. It is talking about the dynamic QGIS expression variables which you see under the Variables section in the expression builder dialogs throughout QGIS. The available variables depend on the current expression context and scope. A variable is referenced in an expression by preceding it with an @ symbol. Have a look at this section of the docs: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables

Comment: @BenW Thanks so much!